# Visual Code / Robot Framework : How can I fold manually under a commentary section?

Tags: visual-studio-code, robotframework, fold

I want to fold my robot framework keywords under a commentary section in Visual Studio Code but I don't find how I can do this.

```
***Settings***

#Inscription

La page doodle S'inscrire
     [Documentation]    ouverture de la page s'inscrire depuis un navigateur
     ...                et vérification que l'on ne peut pas s'inscrire sans remplir les champs
     [Tags]             Inscription

    page_inscription.Aller à la page s'inscrire

Remplir les formulaires
    [Documentation]    Remplir les formulaires necessaires à l'inscription
    [Tags]             Inscription

    page_inscription.Remplir Nom Complet
    page_inscription.Remplir Email
    page_inscription.Remplir Mot De Passe

#Activation

Aller sur la boîte mail
    [Documentation]    Permet d'activer le compte afin de pouvoir se connecter
    [Tags]             Activation

    Ouvrir Navigateur    Chrome
```

Here I want to :

1. fold "La page doodle S'inscrire" and "Remplir les formulaires" under "#Inscription"
2. fold "Aller sur la boîte mail" under "#Activation"

Can someone explain to me ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are referring to the Fold/Unfold Marker Regions.

With your .py files you'll be able to use them like this

[image]

But with your .txt files I don't think it will work unless trying to set up a custom indentation for the RobotFramework keywords to be able to use the `<!-- #region -->`, `<!-- #endregion -->`